# How to remove this extra space next to a checkbox?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-widget, padding, margin

First off I am new to android development and some seemingly easy tasks are frustrating me to no end.  This is a follow on question to what was answered here: [Changing the checkbox size in Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207714/changing-the-checkbox-size-in-android-2-0)

The gist of it is that for some reason there is this extra space that keeps showing up next to my checkboxes (See Below).

[image: Space Next to checkboxes]

Now I have tried to set the width to 1 and it doesn't get any shorter than what is shown.  I have tried to set the width bigger and I can make the size bigger, but no shorter.

Please take a look at the code below and let me know what you see.

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.timeEntriesTable);


        for (int i = 0; i < timeEntries.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Element element = (Element) timeEntries.item(i);
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            CheckBox box = new CheckBox(this);
            box.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_off_background));
            box.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
            box.setWidth(1);
            box.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox box = (CheckBox) v;
                    if (box.isChecked())
                    {
                        box.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_on_background));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        box.setButtonDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_off_background));
                    }

                }
            });

            TextView dateBox = new TextView(this);

            String dateText = element.getAttribute("date");
            dateBox.setText(dateText);
            dateBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            TextView customerBox = new TextView(this);

            String customerName = element.getAttribute("customer");
            customerBox.setText(customerName);
            customerBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            TextView hoursBox = new TextView(this);

            String hours = element.getAttribute("hours");
            hoursBox.setText(hours);
            hoursBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

            TextView test = new TextView(this);
            test.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            test.setText("Test");

            tr.addView(box);                
            tr.addView(dateBox);
            tr.addView(customerBox);
            tr.addView(hoursBox);



            table.addView(tr, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after the input of the two other answerers @adamp and @Phobos.  I stumbled across what worked for me.

[How to set (Text)View attributes programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696843/how-to-set-textview-attributes-programmatically)

By adding this:

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
            lp.width = 15;
            lp.setMargins(3, 5, 0, 0);
            lp.height = 15;
tr.addView(box, lp);
```

I was able to tweak that cell exactly how I wanted it.  It was very strange to me that it wasn't growing the column of the cell it was growing the checkbox itself.  This is because in Android there are no actual cells, it uses the views and their sizes to generate the table apparently.

I have came across no tutorials or anything that has you set the LayoutParams programmatically that way.  Thank you for your help troubleshooting this!

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer to your own question.  I wish more people would do this instead of leaving them unanswered after finding a solution. +1

Comment: No problem.  I to hate when I come across unanswered questions on here or other places.  There was no way I was going to let this go unanswered with what I perceived to be a total lack of quality information on this issue in my searches.  Hopefully it saves someone else the time I had spent pulling my hair out :)

Comment: I hate people answering their own questions with **I found a solution**, and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

That looks suspiciously like the "Time Entries" header is in its own table cell in a header row and the column of checkboxes below it is matching the same width. (See how the right edge of the text lines up perfectly with the date below it?) Since the checkbox's layout_gravity is likely defaulting to `TOP|LEFT`, it's being positioned in the upper left of the cell.

Try altering either the header row or the layout_gravity of the checkboxes.

Comment: So this sent me down the right path to.  I think it had a lot to do with the top header row and how it was trying to resize it.  When I set that to span all 4 it shrank it by about half but there was still a good 10-15 px space.  Then I tried to set the layoutparameters and it vanished altogether.  Which lead me to the answer that worked for me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696843/how-to-set-textview-attributes-programmatically

Comment: Great! For future reference, any XML view attribute that starts with "layout_" is a LayoutParams attribute. The type of LayoutParams you use always depends on the parent view.

Comment: Yeah it was very troublesome because all I could see that you could set was match_parent, and wrap_content... but making my own instance and tweaking it like that was very refreshing to find.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Table Layouts naturally want to make all the cells the same size.  If you want one, or more, to be different sizes then that takes additional parameters.

To shrink all the extra space in your cells add this to your table object

table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

Or to just shrink the first column where your checkbox is

table.setColumnShrinkable(int columnIndex, boolean isShrinkable)

Comment: I tried this and I think it is not working because the header row is spanning across all the columns so it shrinks to that and not the much smaller column in the second row.  However... +1 because I had no idea that was even there... thank you!

Comment: You could make the header row a table row with a blank cell, TITLE, blank cell, blank cell.   This would allow you to shrink the first column without it effecting your title.

Comment: How do you make blank cells in the tablelayout?  Just add a dummy textview or something?

Comment: Awesome thanks I am going to give that a try just for learning sake.